# Determine a product's rating given a known 3-sigma tolerance

Tags: probability, distributions, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn, sigma-algebra

Consider a 100Ω resistor with a 10% tolerance. We can assume this is the 3-sigma value since this is typical in manufacturing. Thus, we can expect ≈99.73% of such resistors to range from 90Ω to 110Ω.

Putting aside the fact that the manufacturer will re-bin resistors with a 5% tolerance, I want to figure out the *average resistor's Ohms value* and express this as a rating.

One idea I had was to use rms. Something like this (using `≈1.11` to convert rms to average):

$\delta=x±10\%=100±10\%=10$

$r=\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}\times1.11}+(x-\delta)=\frac{10}{\sqrt{2}\times1.11}+(100-10)\approx96.37\%$

Remember, I want a rating, hence the percentage. Using this same approach, a 100Ω resistor with a 5% tolerance would have a rating of ≈98.19%.

How accurate is this approach mathematically?

**Alternate approach:**

Looking at the normal distribution, I realize that integration will answer my question.

I know the height of the mode in a normal density is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}$.

What I don't know is the height at 3-sigma, or how to use integration to solve this question.

I'm a software engineer, but not a statistician. How do I calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider that we don't know what is the true distribution of resistance (you might want to look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/157788/resistors-binning-and-weird-distributions)). But, for simplicity (and to go well with the $3\sigma$ assumption), let's say it has a normal distribution. That is, if we have a $100\Omega$ resistor with a silver tolerance band (10%), then $P(R\in[90\Omega,110\Omega])=0.997$. That is the meaning of confidence intervals and the $3\sigma$ notation: It means that no more than 3 out of 1000 resistors produced in this manufacturing line had resistance of more than $110\Omega$ or less than $90\Omega$.

Now, we can decompose this CI in order to get an estimate of the average resistance, but spoiler alert: we'll get that the average is exactly $100\Omega$.

The middle value of the CI is obviously $100\Omega$. We assume $3\sigma=10\Omega$ so the SD for a resistor from this production line is $3.33\Omega$. You can try finding which value of $\mu$ would minimize the equation $ \sqrt{ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  (x-\mu)^2 f(x)dx } - \sigma$ (where $f(x)$ is the normal PDF with parameters $\mu,\sigma$) but then again you'll get that the minimizer is $\mu=100\Omega$.

Should you find any alternative distribution for the resistance of a resistor (I mean, other than the normal), we can try constructing a CI fitting it using [the delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method).

---

Regarding the RMS approach - As far as my knowledge goes (in both electronics and stats), we use RMS to get an approximation for a bunch of measurements, whether it's a dataset or the response to a wave input. I don't think it belongs here, and if you insist on using it then keep in mind that taking $(x-\delta)$ alone is not enough, you should also take $(x+\delta)$ into calculation.

Comment: Thank you. The rms using positive and negative deltas yield identical values with respect to 1, meaning the two average to 1. So. unless I'm missing something, this should be good. I'll need to do quite a bit of study to be able to code the formula. Thank you for your help.